# Any way to fix a shower handle dripping through the stem?

Tags: shower, valve, leaks

Unlike most answers I've found, this valve is not leaking at the seat washer. I still replaced that since I had the valve open. I tried putting some packing inside the concentric nuts, the silver one that holds the cover and the bronze one that the silver one goes into. Still I cannot stop the drip which only happens when the valve is opened to run the water.

The valve while leaking:
[image]

The only discernible markings are around the stem with the word WOLVERINE stamped into the metal.

Here is a picture of the valve stem for further reference:

[image: The stem]

And here is a picture of the manifold the valve goes into behind the wall:

[image: The manifold]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What's the brand and/or model of the valve (if you know it)?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the quick reply. I updated the question with the answer about the brand. Sorry I had to take the original pictures down because I don't have "10 reputation" to post more than 2 links.

Comment: Add URLs that point to the original pictures and someone will be along to edit in the pictures.

Comment: Confirmed, the brand is Wolverine Brass. I located a logo stamped on the stem that matches the company I found online.

Comment: I edited in one picture; the other was basically the same thing.

Comment: You should only need to tighten the packing nut. There are 2 places it could be, for the age that handle may be the packing under the nut may be just a simple cord wrapped around the stem and cramped tight by the packing nut. Sometimes that stuff wears out, sometimes it just needs to be tightened. I have only seen these with one nut, yours has 2, hence the 2 choices.

Answer (score 1):

I did as Jack mentioned in the comments. I got some graphite packing compound and placed it around the stem between the two brass nuts. After tightening all down, some of the packing squeezed out around the stem and the silver nut where the drip was. That has stopped the water for now. I guess this is going to be an ongoing maintenance task until the packing wears away.